# Data duplication between microservices - solve redundancy within ONE service

Tags: duplicates, microservices

Service A and B share small parts of the domain data via a publish/subscribe messaging system. Service B is interested in only one attribute of a domain entity in service A. Service A is the "owner" of this attribute. On attribute change, a specific event dataset is written to an event table in service A and sent to a message topic.

Idea: To avoid data duplication (attribute is in the entity AND event table) move the attribute to the event table and offer a small interface to write/read the attributes from here.

Advantage: Business logic developers of service A do no longer forget to send change events as data is stored in one place.

What do you think about this idea?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Don't do it.

Long answer:

> Idea: To avoid data duplication

There is a difference between duplicated data and redundant data. When you work with distributed systems and service orientation, you do so because you want to simplify interactions and reduce coupling between components. However, there is a cost to this. The more distributed your architecture, the less coupling it has, the more duplication of data will be needed. This is taken to an extreme with microservices, where effectively the same data may be present in many different places.

The instinct to regard such duplication of data as wrong is correct - it is what we are taught when we learn to program and build software! To allow such data duplication seems somehow against best practise. **But**, with microservices data duplication is a *good thing*, an essential feature of your system! It is an enabler of an architectural style with many great benefits. Without duplication of data, you get less distribution and more coupling, which makes your system more expensive to build, own, and change.

So to be clear, I'm not saying that your idea is wrong for sure - it may be the optimal solution for you, but I am saying do not drive your decision making based on avoiding the duplication of data.

Comment: I totally agree! But the question is about saving the same information within ONE service (entity and event table)